# Display files matching a term recursively but don't descend into matching directories

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm trying to write a bash script that searches the whole computer (excluding System files and Homebrew files) for files & folders that contain (their filename) a given term ($1). However, if a folder has been added to the list of results and it contains sub folders/files that (their filename again) contain the search term, then I do not want to add the sub folders/files.

Here's an example of the output I'm trying to get:

```
"/Users/example/Library/Logs/Brave"
"/Users/example/Library/Application Scripts/com.brave.desktop"
"/Users/example/Library/Application Scripts/com.brave.desktop.safari"
"/Users/example/Library/Containers/com.brave.desktop.safari"
# not this last one
"/Users/example/Library/Containers/com.brave.desktop.safari/Data/Library/Application Scripts/com.brave.desktop.safari"
```

To give a bit of context, the output of the script will be used to delete files/folders, which is why I do not want to output the subfolders.

This is my script so far:

```sh
searchResults=($(fd --exclude /System --exclude /usr/local/Homebrew -uu $1 / | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '))

for res in "${searchResults[@]}"
do
    printf '%s\n' $res
done
```

**Example**
Search term: blender
Assuming my computer has these files & folders:

```
"/Users/example/Library/Logs/blender"
"/Users/example/Library/Application Scripts/com.blender.desktop"
"/Users/example/Library/Application Scripts/com.blender.desktop/blenderfile.txt"
"/Users/example/Library/Application Scripts/com.blender.desktop/blenderfolder"
```

The script should output:

```
"/Users/example/Library/Logs/blender"
"/Users/example/Library/Application Scripts/com.blender.desktop"
```

I don't have much knowledge of bash scripting so I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @oguzismail I added an example for clarification. Essentially since I am going to use the search results to delete to delete files/folders, if for example /something and /something/example.txt appeared in the search results, i would then delete /something and then /something/example.txt which would break the script since it would already have been deleted.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue you will find using sed (which you have tagged) is that sed does a greedy match. E.G.

```sh
search="repos" 
results=$(find | sed -n "s/\(.*$search\).*/\1/p" | uniq)
```

Fortunately perl allows for non greedy match you can use this to filter out results which contain the search string more than once.

```sh
search="repos"
results=$(find | sed -n "s/\(.*$search\).*/\1/p" | perl -pe "s/(.*?$search).*/\1/" | uniq)
```

I don't have a MacOS system to test, but I am confident this should work.
(Note you can use fd instead of find if you like) I have not included the logic to exclude those directories since you seem to already have that sorted.

Edit:
Just realized my code could cut off the end of the file or directory names. Here is the fixed version which also uses your original fd command

```sh
search="repos"
results=$(fd --exclude /System --exclude /usr/local/Homebrew -uu $search | perl -pe "s/(.*?$search.*?\/|$).*/\1/i;s/\/$//" | uniq)
```

Comment: It's a good start, thanks! However it trims the results. I have this file: `/Users/example/Library/Caches/com.repos.desktop.ShipIt` and the script outputs `/Users/example/Library/Caches/com.repos`

Comment: Yep I noticed as soon as I posted it, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With traditional *find* you'd do something like the following to list files that contain the search term in their names except those residing in directories that have already been found.

```
#/bin/sh -
find '/' \
  ! \( -path '/System' -prune \) \
  ! \( -path '/usr/local/Homebrew' -prune \) \
  -name "*$1*" -prune
```

You don't need to process its output any further. If you append `-exec rm -rf {} +` to it, those files will be deleted regardless of whether their names contain unusual characters.

I don't know if there is an easier way with *fd* though.